# Call environment variable from another stage in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Generate script') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'sh generate_version.sh new_version.log'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Fetch version') {
            environment {
                version = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''sh grep version: ''').trim()
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'echo "do something: $version"'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('use the version') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'echo $version'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to fetch the version in 3rd stage, ofcourse I can define in the main pipeline, but as you can see I'm getting the variable value in one of the stage, so that won't work for me.

Is there any other way, I can access the **version** environment variable outside of the stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `environment` block inside the `Fetch version` stage limits the scope of the `env.version` variable to this stage only. However, if you want to store a value in the environment variable in one stage, and access this variable in the following stage, you have to assign it inside the `script` block, for instance:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Generate script') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'sh generate_version.sh new_version.log'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Fetch version') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // here we create `env.version` variable that can be access in the later stages
                    env.version = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''sh grep version: ''').trim()
                    sh 'echo "do something: $version"'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('use the version') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "echo $version"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a shorthand version and assign a value to a `version` instead of `env.version`, but this is an implicit binding and making it explicit makes your intention much more straightforward. Another thing worth mentioning - use double quotes when you want to interpolate `$version` variable correctly. Single quotes will print the text as is.