# Not able to access variable declared in environment block in stage block in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have jenkins file as follows

```
pipeline{agent{node{label ...}}
environment{
    var1=""
    var2=""
}
stages{
    stage{
        steps{
            script{
                var1="some string"
                var2="another string"
            }
        }
     }
    stage{
        echo "${var1}"
        echo "${var2}"
    }
}
}
```

After running this I get null values for var1 and var2.
I tried solution provided here [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191849/environment-variable-not-found-in-jenkinsfile) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877237/call-environment-variable-from-another-stage-in-jenkinsfile)

What is missing in my script?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is in your link2. You should:

- get rid of environment section
- use env variables if you want to reference them in next stages:

```
    stage('assign values'){
            steps{
                script{
                    env.VAR1="some string"
                    env.VAR2="another string"
                }
            }
         }
```

- use capital letters for better clarity
- fix error in last stage and add steps section:

```
stage('print'){
            steps{
                echo env.VAR1
                echo env.VAR2
            }
        }
```